# TipTap Collaboration Not Working on Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, web-frontend, tiptap

**Problem:** I have two sessions loading with the same `id` and `token` passed in; yet, the same document isn't loading. All you need for sessions to collaborate is the those attributes to match, correct??

**Framework/Technologies Used:** Next.js

**UI/Screenshots:** As you all can see below, I have the last four digits of the token and ID logged on the UI so you guys can see that both sessions are loading the **exact** same token and ID...

[I have the last four digits of the token and ID logged on the UI so you guys can see that both sessions are loading the exact same token and ID...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzBWO.png)

**Code Snippet:**

```
export default function TextEditor() {
  const CustomDocument = Document.extend({
    content: 'heading block*',
  });
  const getURLTokenAndID = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    return { URL_ID: urlParams.get('id'), URL_TOKEN: urlParams.get('token') };
  };
  const { URL_ID, URL_TOKEN } = getURLTokenAndID();
  const doc = new Y.Doc();
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>(URL_TOKEN || '');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [documentID, setDocumentID] = useState<string>(URL_ID || uniqueID);

 // Redacted the ActionButton implementation

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch token and set loading to false
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      // Fetch token
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/getCollabToken');
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch token');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setToken(data.token);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        // setError(error.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    // Fetch token if URL_TOKEN is not provided
    if (!URL_TOKEN) {
      fetchToken();
    } else {
      // Set collabToken if URL_TOKEN is provided
      setToken(URL_TOKEN);
      if (URL_ID) {
        setDocumentID(URL_ID);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [URL_TOKEN, URL_ID]);

  // TODO: Cleanup usages of 3 useEffects
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!URL_TOKEN) setToken(token || '');
    const provider = new TiptapCollabProvider({
      name: documentID, // any identifier - all connections sharing the same identifier will be synced
      appId: 'rm8441ko',
      token: token,
      document: doc,
    });
    return () => {
      provider.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      CustomDocument,
      StarterKit.configure({
        document: false,
        history: false,
      }),
      Placeholder.configure({
        placeholder: ({ node }) => {
          return node.type.name === 'heading' &&
            node.attrs &&
            node.attrs.levels === 1
            ? 'What’s the song title?'
            : '';
        },
      }),
      Underline,
      Collaboration.configure({
        document: doc,
      }),
    ],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    editor?.commands.setContent(
      '<h1>Content</h1>`
    );
  }, [editor]);

  return loading ? (
    <AiOutlineLoading className={styles.spinner} />
  ) : (
    <>
      <h2>Collab Token: {token.slice(-4)}</h2>
      <h2>DocumentID: {documentID.slice(-4)}</h2>
      <EditorContent editor={editor} className={styles.editorContent} />
    </>
  );
}
```

**What I've Tried:** Followed the [TipTap Collaboration Guide walkthrough](https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/collaboration/guides) almost exactly (minus variable names and flexibility with API routing).